# how to map values in material ui auto-complete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have got data from firebase in "arr" but I dont know how can I use material-ui Auto-Complete? how Can I map "arr" data in Auto-Complete field?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { DBfirebase } from '../../Database/DBfirebase'
import { signUp } from '../../Store/Actions/Auth'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Search } from '../../Store/Actions/Auth'


class AddProduct extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            arr: [],
            productName: '',
            description: '',
            company:''

        }
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
        this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);
        this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this);
        this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this);
    }
    inputHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let multipath = {};
        let productDetails = {
            productName: this.state.productName,
            description: this.state.description,
           company: this.state.company,
        }
        console.log(productDetails)
        DBfirebase.refAddProduct.push(productDetails);
        browserHistory.push('/home/view-purchases')

    }

//working code
     onSearch(e) {
        let _self = this;
       // e.preventDefault()
        let ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/AddedProducts/');
        _self.arr = [];

      //  console.log(this.refs.selectedCity.value)
        //  ref.orderByChild('city').equalTo(this.refs.selectedCity.value).once('value', function (snapshot) {
  ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {



            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {

                _self.arr.push(childSnapshot.val())
                console.log("arr", _self.arr)

            })
            _self.props.serachProducts(_self.arr)
            _self.setState({
                arr: _self.props.storeReducer.products

            })
        });
  }

   componentWillMount(){
       this.onSearch();
    }

    handleUpdateInput = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      arr: [
        value,
        value + value,
        value + value + value,
      ],
    });
  };


    render() {
        return (
            <div ><center>
                <AddProductForm signUpState={this.state} _inputHandler={this.inputHandler} _submit={this.submit} />
            </center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// AddProduct.contextTypes = {
//     router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
// }


const dataSourceConfig = {
  text: 'textKey',
  value: 'valueKey',
};

class AddProductForm extends React.Component {


    render() {
        console.log("this.props.signUpState.arr",this.props.signUpState.arr)
        const datasource = this.props.signUpState.arr;
        return (
            <div >

                <h1>Add New Product</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.props._submit} >
                    <AutoComplete
          hintText="Product Name"
          filter={AutoComplete.noFilter}
          openOnFocus={true}
        //  dataSource={this.props.signUpState.arr}
            dataSource={datasource}
          onUpdateInput={this.props.signUpState.handleUpdateInput}
          dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
        />
                    <TextField
                        hintText="Product Name"
                        name="productName"
                        value={this.props.signUpState.productName}
                     floatingLabelText="Product Name"
                        onChange={this.props._inputHandler}
                        /><br /><br />

                    <TextField
                        type="text"
                        hintText="description"
                        name="description"
                        value={this.props.signUpState.description}
                       floatingLabelText="description"
                        onChange={this.props._inputHandler}
                        /><br /><br />


                        <TextField
                        type="text"
                        hintText="company"
                        name="company"
                        value={this.props.signUpState.company}
                        floatingLabelText="company"
                        onChange={this.props._inputHandler}
                        /><br />
                        <br />

                 <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Add Product" primary={false} secondary={true} /> <br /><br />
                </form>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

AddProductForm.PropTypes = {
    _inputHandler: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    _submit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
     console.log(state.ProductReducer)
    return {
        storeReducer: state.ProductReducer
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
        serachProducts: (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            dispatch(Search(data))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddProduct);
```

I have got data from firebase in "arr" but I dont know how can I use material-ui Auto-Complete? how Can I map "arr" data in Auto-Complete field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import { DBfirebase } from '../../Database/DBfirebase'
import { signUp } from '../../Store/Actions/Auth'
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Search } from '../../Store/Actions/Auth'


class AddProduct extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            arr: [],
            productName: '',
            description: '',
            company:''

        }
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
        this.inputHandler = this.inputHandler.bind(this);
        this.onSearch = this.onSearch.bind(this);
        this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this);
    }
    inputHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    submit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let multipath = {};
        let productDetails = {
            productName: this.state.productName,
            description: this.state.description,
           company: this.state.company,
        }
        console.log(productDetails)
        DBfirebase.refAddProduct.push(productDetails);
        browserHistory.push('/home/view-purchases')

    }

//working code
     onSearch(e) {
        let _self = this;
       // e.preventDefault()
        let ref = firebase.database().ref().child('/AddedProducts/');
        _self.arr = [];

      //  console.log(this.refs.selectedCity.value)
        //  ref.orderByChild('city').equalTo(this.refs.selectedCity.value).once('value', function (snapshot) {
  ref.once('value', function (snapshot) {



            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {

                _self.arr.push(childSnapshot.val())
                console.log("arr", _self.arr)

            })
            _self.props.serachProducts(_self.arr)
            _self.setState({
                arr: _self.props.storeReducer.products

            })
        });
  }

   componentWillMount(){
       this.onSearch();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div ><center>
                <AddProductForm signUpState={this.state} _inputHandler={this.inputHandler} _submit={this.submit} />
            </center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// AddProduct.contextTypes = {
//     router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
// }

class AddProductForm extends React.Component {


    render() {
        console.log("this.props.signUpState.arr",this.props.signUpState.arr)

   { this.props.signUpState.arr.map((v, i) => {
                                            return (
                                              datasource.push(v.productName)
                                            )
                                        })}

        return (
            <div >

                <h1>Add New Product</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.props._submit} >
                    <AutoComplete
          hintText="Product Name"
          filter={AutoComplete.noFilter}
          openOnFocus={true}
        //  dataSource={this.props.signUpState.arr}
            dataSource={datasource}
      //    onUpdateInput={this.props.signUpState.handleUpdateInput}
        //  dataSourceConfig={dataSourceConfig}
        />
                    <TextField
                        hintText="Product Name"
                        name="productName"
                        value={this.props.signUpState.productName}
                     floatingLabelText="Product Name"
                        onChange={this.props._inputHandler}
                        /><br /><br />

                    <TextField
                        type="text"
                        hintText="description"
                        name="description"
                        value={this.props.signUpState.description}
                       floatingLabelText="description"
                        onChange={this.props._inputHandler}
                        /><br /><br />


                        <TextField
                        type="text"
                        hintText="company"
                        name="company"
                        value={this.props.signUpState.company}
                        floatingLabelText="company"
                        onChange={this.props._inputHandler}
                        /><br />
                        <br />

                 <RaisedButton type="submit" label="Add Product" primary={false} secondary={true} /> <br /><br />
                </form>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

AddProductForm.PropTypes = {
    _inputHandler: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    _submit: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => { 
     console.log(state.ProductReducer)
    return {
        storeReducer: state.ProductReducer
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
        serachProducts: (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            dispatch(Search(data))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddProduct);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually data from firebase come in object... So first get the keys of object using Object.keys(objectname) then store all keys in Array ... After getting the keys of object then start mapping on Arrays of key and in map call ur object with keys like obj[keys] ..

Comment: Thanks for your answer